# Create new array by comparing two different arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays like this

```
const Arr1 = [
  {
    KeyToMatch: {
      Cl: 2,
      Ro: 5,
      Ge: 1,
    },
    Image: "image.jpg",
    Name: "example no 1",
  },
  {
    KeyToMatch: {
      Cl: 3,
      Ro: 1,
      Ge: 2,
    },
    Image: "image2.jpg",
    Name: "example no 2",
  },
  {
    KeyToMatch: {
      Cl: 9,
      Ro: 2,
      Ge: 1,
    },
    Image: "image2.jpg",
    Name: "example no 2",
  },
];


const Arr2 = [
  {
    KeyToMatch: {
      Cl: 3,
      Ro: 1,
      Ge: 2,
    },
    MoreDatas: [],
  },
  {
    KeyToMatch: {
      Cl: 2,
      Ro: 5,
      Ge: 1,
    },
    MoreDatas: [],
  },
];
```

in above two arrays, i need to pick every item from from arr2 and match its "KeyToMatch's key by each key & value" with KeyToMatch in Arr1. if any we get any matched result then merge "this item from Arr2 and matched item from Arr1" into a new array that we want as final output.

final output i expect is.

```
[
  {
    KeyToMatch: {
      Cl: 3,
      Ro: 1,
      Ge: 2,
    },
    MoreDatas: [],
    Image: "image2.jpg",
    Name: "example no 2",
  },
  {
    KeyToMatch: {
      Cl: 2,
      Ro: 5,
      Ge: 1,
    },
    MoreDatas: [],
    Image: "image.jpg",
    Name: "example no 1",
  },
];
```

not sure how to do it here, one way i think is to merge both the Arrays and filter merged arrays where MoreData is null, not available or undefined, but that will not give desired result and not correct at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first key the first array by the keys in a Map, using a JSON representation of the three primitive values in that key (as array). Then map the second array by first finding in that map the corresponding object and merging them. Filter out the keys that didn't math:

```js
const Arr1 = [{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 2,Ro: 5,Ge: 1,},Image: "image.jpg",Name: "example no 1",},{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 3,Ro: 1,Ge: 2,},Image: "image2.jpg",Name: "example no 2",},{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 9,Ro: 2,Ge: 1,},Image: "image2.jpg",Name: "example no 2",},];
const Arr2 = [{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 3,Ro: 1,Ge: 2,},MoreDatas: [],},{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 2,Ro: 5,Ge: 1,},MoreDatas: [],},];


const getKey = ({KeyToMatch: {Cl, Ro, Ge}}) => JSON.stringify([Cl, Ro, Ge]);
const map = new Map(Arr1.map(o => [getKey(o), o]));
const res = Arr2.map(o => {
    const other = map.get(getKey(o));
    return other && {...o, ...other};
}).filter(Boolean);

console.log(res);
```

If the keys are dynamic, then extract all the key/value pairs, sort them and then stringify them as array. So this just affects the `getKey` function:

```js
const Arr1 = [{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 2,Ro: 5,Ge: 1,},Image: "image.jpg",Name: "example no 1",},{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 3,Ro: 1,Ge: 2,},Image: "image2.jpg",Name: "example no 2",},{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 9,Ro: 2,Ge: 1,},Image: "image2.jpg",Name: "example no 2",},];
const Arr2 = [{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 3,Ro: 1,Ge: 2,},MoreDatas: [],},{KeyToMatch: {Cl: 2,Ro: 5,Ge: 1,},MoreDatas: [],},];


const getKey = o => JSON.stringify(
    Object.keys(o.KeyToMatch).sort()
          .flatMap(key => [key, o.KeyToMatch[key]])
);

const map = new Map(Arr1.map(o => [getKey(o), o]));
const res = Arr2.map(o => {
    const other = map.get(getKey(o));
    return other && {...o, ...other};
}).filter(Boolean);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: as this serves above purpose well but what if those KeysToMatch are dynamic, I mean not always just Cl, Ro,Ge, but sometimes, there are few more keys are there. because my data has lot few more keys inside KeyToMatch to match.

Comment: My first reaction is: that is a bad idea for a key. But if you really want to go that way, it can be made dynamic, but it will be slower. Shall I update my answer in that way?

Comment: Yes Please, I want to understand, how in that way it will work.

Comment: OK, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```js
const res = Arr2.map((x, i) => ({ ...x, ...Arr1[i] }))
```